Optimise Category Page Speed
The category page takes between 4 to 5 seconds to load, occasionally extending to 6 or 7 seconds. The page doesn't have a large number of product listings, with a maximum of around 50, but pagination is applied, so only 12 products are loaded initially. However, there is a color attribute with over 9,000 colors, and removing this attribute from the layer navigation causes a delay of approximately 3 seconds. My ultimate aim is to quickly redirect users to the category page and then load all layer navigation and products asynchronously via AJAX. Is this achievable, or do you have any alternative suggestions for implementation? If there's a freely available extension providing this functionality, I'd be delighted to use it. Alternatively, if anyone has a custom implementation available, I would appreciate it if they could share it.

Starting from the basics: do you use Varnish cache?

Yes, I'm utilizing it. For your information, the first time I open the category, it takes some time to load. However, upon revisiting the category, it loads quickly on my end

If you often times experience "the first time" loading, it may point at early cache eviction. There are numerous cases where modules or theme code unnecessarily clear entire cache. swissup themes did it.

Your time to first byte (TTFB) is pretty high.
Here is what I'd do:

Connect your site to an online PHP code profiler (new relic, tideways etc)
See what CPU cycles are spent on, you probably have a slow function call.

Product page should load in 1-2 seconds.
